# Magento 2.3 Attempt to load value of nonexistent EAV attribute

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue https://prnt.sc/omb7wd

Comment: You have migrate data from m1 to m2 ??

Comment: No. not at all. i have been using magento 2.3 from beginning

Comment: Ok this attribute ids exist on eav_attribute table ?

Comment: Which column i need to check entity_attribute_id or attribute_id?

Comment: You can check attribute_id

Comment: Yes 93 and 177 exist in attribute_id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96841/discussion-between-limbani-himanshu-and-nafisa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please create backup of your database and delete attribute id on
>   eav_attribute table and check
>   **try it may be work**